# How to create a local notification which does not show an alert but only wakes up the app to perform a calculation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification, multitasking

My app needs to perform certain background tasks throughout the day without that the user always has to "ok" a dialogue. Is it possible to create a local notification which only awakens the app to let it perform a small task?

Comment: No it is required that the user interacts with the notification. That's the limitation. [Duplicate of this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301793/can-uilocalnotification-be-used-to-wake-up-a-task-that-is-in-the-background?answertab=active#tab-top)